# Different results between online C compiler and compiling in cmd while trying to implement linkedlists

Tags: c, linked-list, compilation, online-compilation

Actually the title is pretty self explanotary, I implement the linkedlist in online C compiler and the code correctly adds elements to the list, prints the list and then deletes the last element of the linkedlist. But when I compile the program in MinGW on cmd it enters a infinite loop, it doesn't even show the elements added just some random numbers looping and I haven't been able to pin-point the problem.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct node{
    int data ;
    struct node *next ;
}node;
//
node* newNode(int value){
    node *n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    n->data = value;
    n->next = NULL;
}
//
typedef struct list{
    node *head;
    node *tail;
}list;
//
list* add(list *liste, int value){
    node *n = newNode(value);
    if(liste->tail == NULL){
        liste->tail = n;
    }
    n->next = liste->head;
    liste->head = n;
    return liste;
}
//
void gez(list *liste){
    node *ix = liste->head;
    while(ix != NULL){
        printf("%d\n",ix->data);
        ix = ix->next;
    }
}
//
list* cikar(list *liste){
    
    node *ix = liste->head;
    while (ix->next != liste->tail){
        ix = ix->next;
        }
    liste->tail = ix;
    ix->next = NULL;
    return liste;
}
//
int main(){
    list *l = malloc(sizeof(list));
    l = add(l,4);
    l = add(l,8);
    l = add(l,16);
    gez(l);
    l = cikar(l);
    printf("\n");
    gez(l);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any C++ code in there; removed irrelevant tag...

Comment: Does your compiler show some warning about "reaching end of non-void function  `newNode` without return value" or similar?

Comment: It is typical of undefined behavior to work in some cases and not others

Comment: First add call - 'n->next = liste->head;', head is not initialized at that time:(

Comment: Oh, nor tail in '  if(liste->tail == NULL)'.

Comment: Did you run this under a debugger at all?

Comment: What do you expect to happen with last node in `cikar` after you remove it from the list? Where do you want to free it?

Answer (score 1):

Your code has several bugs:

1. `head` and `tail` have no initial value. This will cause indefinite behaviour in `add`. Change `malloc` to `calloc` will by default NULL initialize them or you have to manually do so.
2. **`newNode`** has no return value. Return `n`.
3. You didn't free memory when removing node. Before setting `ix->next = NULL` `free(ix->next)`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, lol I actually solved the problems regarding 1 and 2 but third one never came to mind, thank you!